# Posting to Facebook Page through API as the page (with admin rights)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to run a background service in Ruby to post to my Facebook page once a day. What's the best way to do this? I've read through the Graph API, but most of their documentation relies on first requesting permissions from the User. How do I grant those permissions for my own use and not the end user of my app? For example, Twitter gives you authentication tokens to connect to your own accounts.

A lot of the answers about the Graph API here are outdated. I'm using Ruby, so any recommendations for gems or any of the SDKs on their website.

**Update**

Thanks to @oldergod for the response. I have an updated question.

When I do this, I am able to post as the `myPageName` to `myPageName`'s wall.

```
@graph.put_connections("myPageName", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")
```

But when I do this:

```
@graph.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!", :link => "http://google.com")
```

It posts to `myPageName` as `me`

What am I doing wrong? I have requested `manage_pages` permissions.

Comment: You can use the graph console to get tokens for your account or page you administrate. Then to for the gem, there is fbgraph and koala. I have used Koala so far and it's good.

Comment: Then you better explain what you were expecting

Comment: You need to get a _page_ access token – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *Well, definitely the gem you are looking for is [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala).*

**Update:**

As it seems, you are having some problem setting the actual configuration of Koala gem. Let's go through every step.

You need to setup a new `Koala::Facebook::API`. Despite of being a horrible name, this is really the connection to your profile user. To set up this you need to access the [Facebook Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?) and click **Get Access Token** button (make sure you are logged with the account you wanna post message's to). just **copy that access token**.

```
@user = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
```

Use that access_token to set this new `@user`. Now whenever you mention *"me"* in any **Graph API** request on a @user, you'll be mentioning this user (@user) as the target for that request. "me" is just the facebook ID for the user itself.

The final step is just to post to your user's feed page.

```
@user.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")
```

---

So, if you want to post as a page on your wall. You can do so by

```
@user = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
page_access_token = @user.get_connections('me', 'accounts').first['access_token'] #this gets the users first page.
@page = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_access_token)
@page.put_connections(user_id, "feed", :message => "Page writting to user's wall!")
```

Just go to graph.facebook.com/user_path and get the your_ID.

Comment: I figured it out last night. The part that is missing from here is that I needed a new page specific token by doing `@user.get_connections('me', 'accounts').first['access_token']` and use that to make the call. Your method caused me to post to the Wall as my personal profile. If you could add this part in (or correct me), I can accept the answer!

Comment: No, I want to post to the wall of a PAGE I own and manage as the page.

Comment: Fixed, sorry I'm kinda focused on other stuff. Should've read what you were saying since the start.

Comment: Made one more edit. Wanted to post to the page itself. so it would be `put_connections("me"...`

Comment: The token that we get from the aforementioned link expires, so what is the best way to get a new token each time? Do we need to setup a callback url and then get the token that way?

Comment: I am attempting to build a tool that automatically posts to facebook through custom rake task.  How can I accomplish that with koala? doesnt the token expire?

Comment: @Fdwillis I'm having the same issue... how did you solve it?