# Can I program my app to create facebook posts after I create an object (based off of the object)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a model called Articles with attributes :title, :content, :url and :image can I use these to dynamically create Facebook posts through the Facebook API? Are there any rails gems that help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Koala gem still the best way to handle Facebook API requests on Ruby.

[Relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559602/2620080)

Read the [GitHub Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) documentation for any changes or implementation problems.